# Stacking 301 redirects? .net to .com, www, https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have been struggling getting this chain to work:
I want to point `example.net` to `example.com` and point everything to `https://www.example.com`.

So, we have: `example.net, www.example.net, example.com`, and `www.example.com` that all need to land on `https://www.example.com`.

I can get everything but `https` to work or `https` for the `.com` site only.

Any way to set this up?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case, we want to know what are you using as a host? Apache, Ngix? or you just want to use a DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

First to redirect `example.net` to `example.com` , put the following code in `example.net` main root `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)   https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Then in `example.com` main root .htaccess file put the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear your browser cache and test it .

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get to this work with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#WordPress code
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```